# Facing crash when Posting the data to MVC WEB API Controller from Class Library project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

*Facing issue while posting the data to MVC Web API controller through Class Library project.*

MVC Web API is hosted on Localhost at Port 84.

**Class Library Code that sends request**

```
public String Put(OM_ServicesType obj)
{
    string URI = "http://localhost:84/WebAPIServiceType/Put");
    String myParameters = "ServiceType=qa&description=qa&Sid=1";

    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = 
                                                  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<String>(HtmlResult);
    }
}
```

**Below is the crash**

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

**MVC Web API Code**

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int Sid, string ServiceType, string description)
{
    var obj = new Dal_ServiceType { ServicesTypeID = Sid, Name = ServiceType, 
                                              Description = description};
    var re = obj.Put();
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { ErrorMessage = re });
}
```

Comment: You are sending a GET request to a method you have set with an HttpPost attribute.  You need to either change the attribute to HttpGet or send a POST request.

Comment: UploadString method is for posting the data

Comment: Don't think that's going to work.  Your API method expects three parameters, no way for it figure out that the string is really an int and two strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.

***Code in WEB API Controller Action Method***

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Action_Method_Name([FromBody] ClassName obj)
{
    var objUpdated = new Dal_Provider
    {
        ProviderID = obj.ProviderID,
        ZipCode = obj.ZipCode
    };
    var re = objUpdated.Post();
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { ErrorMessage = re });
}
```

***Code to call the Web API***

```
public String Post(ClassName obj)
{
    String url = string.Format("{0}{1}", "DomainName comes here",
                    "Controller Name/Action Method Name");
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var responseMessage = httpClient.PostAsync(url, 
            new ObjectContent<ClassName>(obj, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())).Result;
    return responseMessage.ReasonPhrase;
}
```